# App.config exception : Configuration System Failed to Initialize

Tags: asp.net, app-config

I'm trying to use the App.config file to store some parameters but I keep getting a `System.Configuration.ConfigurationException : Configuration system failed to initialize` when I try to access my appSettings.

Here is my App.config file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
  </configSections>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1" />
  </startup>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="test" value="1" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <membership defaultProvider="ClientAuthenticationMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="ClientAuthenticationMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.ClientServices.Providers.ClientFormsAuthenticationMembershipProvider, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" serviceUri="" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <roleManager defaultProvider="ClientRoleProvider" enabled="true">
      <providers>
        <add name="ClientRoleProvider" type="System.Web.ClientServices.Providers.ClientRoleProvider, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" serviceUri="" cacheTimeout="86400" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

And here's how I try to access my data and where I get the exception :

```
string test = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["test"];
```

I saw the problem could come from the missing `<configSections>` (not the case here) or the .NET version (I'm using 4.5.1 so it seems ok too).

I just can't shake it out, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you really have `...` in the app config section?

Comment: No of course not, it's just I have many parameters but they are specific to my company so I can't display them. I'll remove them to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 0):

After more investigating, I found what was going wrong.

I had some OracleDB mapping in a configuration file located in `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Config\machine.config`.